# Getting scrambled replies from DHT bootstraps for Bittorrent

Tags: java, character-encoding, bittorrent, dht

I'm trying to implement a DHT node in the Bittorrent mainline. So far I got a connection in and out against a bootstrap node, the query seems to be fine according to some bencoded examples but part of the result I'm getting back is all scrambled (the parts containing the actual data):

```
d2:ip6:µ§ û©Å1:rd2:id20:ëÿ6isQÿJì)Íº«òûãF|Âge1:t2:aa1:y1:re
```

This is my code so far:

```
private static String serverName = "router.utorrent.com";
private static int port = 6881;
private static String packet = "d1:ad2:id20:abcdefghij0123456789e1:q4:ping1:t2:aa1:y1:qe";
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    int port = Main.port;
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(Main.serverName);
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

    byte[] buf = Main.packet.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, port);
    socket.send(packet);
    byte[] recBuf = new byte[2048];
    DatagramPacket recPacket = new DatagramPacket(recBuf, recBuf.length);

    socket.receive(recPacket);

    System.out.println(new String(extract(recPacket)));
}

  private static byte[] extract(DatagramPacket packet) {
        byte[] data = packet.getData();
        int offset = packet.getOffset();
        int length = packet.getLength();

        byte[] copy = new byte[length];
        System.arraycopy(data, offset, copy, 0, copy.length);

        return copy;
      }
```

I'm not sure whether I have a chartset problem or there is some encoding I couldn't find specified anywhere.

Comment: since you're writing it in java, my own implementation might be of interest to you: https://github.com/the8472/mldht

Comment: It is, and it seems it is further ahead of mine. Thanks!

Comment: It works perfectly against a redis instance I have running. Secondarily I'm also looking at actively searching through DHT for nodes hosting particular infohashes. I guess it should be even easier than what you have going on. Got any references maybe?

Comment: I have no CLI or other kind of UI for this yet, but essentially you just have to issue a [PeerLookupTask](https://github.com/the8472/mldht/blob/master/src/lbms/plugins/mldht/kad/tasks/PeerLookupTask.java#L71) which then provides various ways to get scrape or peer list results. I guess you can ask questions via github issues if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your response looks correct to me. It sounds like you expect the DHT protocol to only use ascii characters, it doesn't. The 160 bit node ID is transferred as 20 bytes and the IP and port is transferred as 6 bytes.

see the [protocol specification](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html).